# Regarding the proof of $f \circ g$ is injective does not imply $f$ is injective.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

The proof of this question mainly revolves around using the methods of construction. For instance, we construct $g$ such that it maps $x \in g$ to 2 elements $a,b \in D_f$, then $f$ maps $a,b$ to $y \in R_f$. This allows us to find a construction that fulfills  $f \circ g$ is injective but $f$ is not injective. Now I have a question. This construction is based on the fact that we construct $g$ to be a one to many relation and is thus no longer a function, which results in the whole proof being nonsensical. So how do I reconcile this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.  It is obvious that the injectivity of $f\circ g$ does not generally  imply the injectivity of $f$.  Consider, say, $g:\{1\}\to \{1,2\}$ given by $g(1)=1$ and $f:\{1,2\}\to \{1\}$ given by $f(1)=1=f(2)$.   If you, say, have a reference to a specific proof or argument that you can't follow, perhaps you should include that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is exactly what I meant! You have constructed $g$ that is a one to many relation which does not satisfy the criteria of $g$ being a function.

Comment: What are you talking about?  $g$ takes a single value to a single value.  It is a perfectly well defined function.  It's even injective (of course, $f\circ g$ injective *does* imply that $g$ is injective).  Of course, $g$ is not *surjective* but nobody said it had to be.  To be sure:  if you add the requirement that $g$ be surjective, then the injectivity of $f\circ g$ does imply the injectivity of $f$.

Comment: Perhaps you are unsure of the notation.  If it clarifies matters:  Let $A=\{1\}$ be a set with a single element and let $B=\{x,y\}$ be a set with two elements.  I have changed the names of the elements in $B$ to forestall what might be another point of confusion for you.  We define a function  $g$ from $A$ to $B$ which takes  $1$ to $x$.  The point $y$ is not in the image of $g$.  We then define a function $f$ from $B$ to $A$ by $f(x)=1=f(y)$.  The composition $f\circ g$ is the identity on $A$.  It is obviously injective, though $f$ is not.

Comment: Oh I see now, the notation really confused me. I fully understand now. Thanks so much for the help! I initially thought if $g : {1} \to {1,2} $ means that ${1,2}$ is the image of $g$, thats where the confusion lies.